# Stop executing code after first condition?

Tags: jquery

```
if(id==2)
    {
      alert(id);
    }

$.ajax{(

     //code here

     });
```

In this code i want to stop the code from moving to the ajax. I want it to stop at if , if id is 2. I searched and got an answer ie. `return false` after if statement. Will it cause any problem in executing the problem if i use `return false`. Is there any other way?

**Sorry for posting it now , i dont want to use else** 
I want some information what return false; do . I shall be grateful if someone explain me

Comment: You could put the `$.ajax` in an `else` block.

Comment: your `if` doesn't stop next code block from running. What were you expecting? Is this being run in a loop? If so provide more code

Comment: If you don't want to use `else` then you'd better show more code that gives a good reason why, because `else` is exactly what you have asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code you posted is within a function the `return false` statement is just the same as any other `return` statement. As defined by *w3schools*:

> Sometimes you want your function to return a value back to where the call was made. This is possible by using the return statement.
>
> When using the return statement, the function will stop executing, and return the specified value.

So the `return false` will return a boolean value (in this case false) to where the call was made and of course it will interrupt the execution of the function.

It will not affect in other way your function.

Here you can find more on how to use js functions http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp

Answer (score 2):

You can also use "else" clause to execute Ajax code....

Answer (score 0):

You might wonna "return 2" in this case and check for the return value in the calling function or alternatively you can use else

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this?

```
if (id !== 2) {
    $.ajax{()};
}
else
    alert(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

```
if(id==2)
    { 
      alert(id);
    }
else 
    {
      $.ajax{(
      //code here 
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Return false; is only allowed from inside a function. If you're in a loop you can use break; to jump out of the loop.

In this case, you have to use an else block.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript and another languages, the "return" is responsible for returning values and finish the block. You can see the the javascript documentation.

[JS FUNCTIONS](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp)